# What effect does linking your weapons have?

Tags: strike-suit-zero

You can link your weapons by pressing <kbd>X</kbd>, increasing their rate of fire. Does doing this have any effects beyond the obvious (increased burst DPS, faster energy drain), like affecting your sustained DPS? Assuming my accuracy stays the same through an engagement, should I link my weapons?

Answer (score 1):

According to one of the loading-screen hints,

> Linking your plasma cannons doubles your damage but also doubles your energy drain.

So what you see is what you get: you fire twice as many bullets, and run out of energy twice as fast.

The effectiveness of linking weapons depends on how *high* your accuracy is.

- If you have truly abysmal accuracy, then you should link your weapons, because your enemies' shields could regenerate before you get another hit in. Link your weapons and pray that you manage to hit, because you aren't going to take anyone down if their shields keep regenerating.  (Fun fact: I used the wrong joystick on my gamepad at first. Do you know how hard it is to hit an enemy when your joystick has an up-down axis and a roll-left/right axis?)
- If you have poor accuracy, then you're going to like the fact that your next shot comes sooner with un-linked weapons, because killing your jinky enemies takes a long time and you don't want to miss those fleeting moments when your enemy is actually in your sights.
- If you have high accuracy, then the very short time-to-enemy-death means you can go looking for the next target faster. If you're good at this game, then you should be linking your weapons, slaughtering your enemies as quickly as you can pump out bullets, and seek out your next hapless target while your energy regenerates.

Comment: Does linking weapons have any hidden effects?

Comment: Alas, I simply don't know. I'm assuming that it's just the same as firing the same weapon multiple times, but I don't have conclusive evidence to back it up.